# Best way to overload a function with identical signatures?

Tags: matlab

Consider the following MATLAB function that must have two overloads whose signatures are identical in terms of number of arguments and data types:

```
% Overload 1
output = myFunction(5) % Does something

% Overload 2
output = myFunction(5) % Does something different
```

Suppose that both overloads only accept integers. So there is no way to guess which overload is the right one.

Note that making two different functions is not an option for this example. They must be overloads of the same function.

I guess the only way out would be to add an extra argument to one of the overloads like this:

```
% Overload 1
output = myFunction(5) % Does something

% Overload 2
output = myFunction(5,'hey') % Does something different
```

Is this the best way to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do. Should overload 1 behave on all integers different to overload 2? Why can't you just rename them?

Comment: Let me clarify, the function has 2 overloads, but they are equal in arity and data types, so there is no possible way to distinguish them. Making two different functions is not an option for this case, since they must be overloads of the same function.

Comment: How/where are the two functions defined? (eg. they can't both be files in the local directory with the same name because two files can't have the same name)

Comment: @MatthewGunn There is only one function: `myFunction` and all the code is stored in one single `.m` file. The function can perform two different tasks based on which overload you call. The problem is that both overloads require the same number of arguments and are also of the same type. So I am asking what would be your approach to effectively distinguish between the two overloads. I guess the only way out would be to add an extra argument to one of the overloads, but I would like to hear some other suggestions.

Comment: It seems to me that adding an extra argument is probably what you have to do. You alternatively could put them in separate packages and call something like `package1.myFunction` and `package2.myFunction`, but if the code has to reside in the same file, I think an additional argument is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `varargin` to do this. `varargin` is the cell array used to specify that the function can accept multiple inputs. The n-th input is accessed using `varargin{n}` (note the curly braces). So, the simple example of `varargin` usage can be:

```
function output = myFunction(varargin)
if length(varargin) == 1
    output = varargin{1}.^2;
elseif length(varargin) == 2
    if strcmp(varargin{2},'cube')
        output = varargin{1}.^3;
    end
else
    error('Too many input arguments')
end
```

The above code checks the number of inputs. If there is only one input, it is squared, if there are two of them and second input is `'cube'` then the first argument is cubed. If there are more than 2 inputs or zero of them, then error message is returned.

Test:

```
>> myFunction(5)

ans =

    25

>> myFunction(5,'cube')

ans =

   125
```